# Помогите перевести из функции в цикл js

Tags: javascript

Пишу проект кофемашины. Помогите, пожалуйста, перезаписать данный код для расчета сдачи в монетках из функции в цикл с помощью while и for и выводом в console.log Например если 50р - сдача 10рублей по 5.

```
   function oldgetChange(num) {
                    if (num >= 10) {
                        console.log(10);
                        getChange(num - 10);
                    } else if (num >= 5) {
                        console.log(5);
                        getChange(num - 5);
                    } else if (num >= 2) {
                        console.log(2);
                        getChange(num - 2);
                    } else if (num >= 1) {
                        console.log(1);
                        getChange(num - 1);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Вся сдача выдана!");
                    }
                }
```

код полностью:

```
<body>
        <div class="container pt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row cofee_txt">
                        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(48, 'Американо')"></div>
                        <span>Американо - 48 руб.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cofee_txt">
                        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(53, 'Эспрессо')"></div>
                        <span>Эспрессо - 53 руб.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cofee_txt">
                        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(61, 'Латте')"></div>
                        <span>Латте - 61 руб.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cofee_txt">
                        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(59, 'Капучино')"></div>
                        <span>Капучино - 59 руб.</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cofee_txt">
                        <div class="coffee_btn" onclick="getCoffee(78, 'Мокаччино')"></div>
                        <span>Мокаччино - 78 руб.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row pt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <div class="" id="display">Внесите деньги.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Сколько у вас денег?" id="money" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            let money = document.getElementById("money");
            let display = document.getElementById("display");

            function getCoffee(price, name) {
                if (money.value >= price) {
                    money.value = money.value - price;

                    display.innerHTML = name + " готов!";
                } else {
                    display.innerHTML = name + " только за деньги!";
                }
            }

            function oldgetChange(num) {
                if (num >= 10) {
                    console.log(10);
                    getChange(num - 10);
                } else if (num >= 5) {
                    console.log(5);
                    getChange(num - 5);
                } else if (num >= 2) {
                    console.log(2);
                    getChange(num - 2);
                } else if (num >= 1) {
                    console.log(1);
                    getChange(num - 1);
                } else {
                    console.log("Вся сдача выдана!");
                }
            }

        </script>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```